# Google Keep ArrayList via implicit intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-keep

I want to share my `ListView` data model via an implicit intent in Google Keep. But I can't find any Intent EXTRA suitable for this purpose. Basically I'm trying to do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                myList.add("TEXT1");
                myList.add("TEXT2");
                i.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myList);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
```

But it seems that `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` accepts only a single `String` object.
Any advice on how to achieve my goal?